# Created a custom styled PayPal checkout button on Shopify, but I was previously told this wasn't possible

Tags: paypal, shopify

As the subject states, I created a PayPal Checkout button by simply adding the HTML code for the button and modified the text and remove the PayPal logo image.

Normally the code below would be used to generate the button, which of course is limiting:

```
{{ content_for_additional_checkout_buttons }}
```

However, I have instead added this HTML in its stead:

```
<div class="paypal-checkout-button">
  <button name="goto_pp" type="submit" id="paypal-express-button" class="additional-checkout-button additional-checkout-button--paypal-express" value="paypal_express">
    CHECKOUT WITH PAYPAL
  </button>
</div>
```

The button's functionality is perfectly fine; I even processed a test payment through it. A developer friend of mine told me it wasn't possible without some hacky solution; however, the simple HTML snippet above seems to be a perfect solution to customizing the PayPal button on the cart / product page.

Am I missing anything? Or is this perfectly fine to do?

Appreciate any you can provide on the matter.

Comment: Ask your 'friend' why it isn't possible, and why your solution appears to contradict him. No reason why you have to account for your colleague's beliefs. Not a real question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the button on the cart that Shopify people have issues/problems with.

It's the button on the checkout and that can't be modified (without a lot of hassle) unless the store owner has a Plus account. That is almost certainly what your developer friend is talking about.

Not to mention, of course, that changing the appearance of the button or forcing it not to appear before the Shopify checkout process is a violation of the PayPal express user agreement.

Comment: I kept all of the PayPal logos and etc. exactly as displayed on their button examples, so I'm not worried about violation. The only thing I did was match the actual button design to the standard checkout button design (height, width, shadows).

So doing this won't be an issue at all? I actually disabled the Paypal button at the checkout and moved it to a modal cart.

Thanks BigA